# Vendor MIME types and API versioning in Symfony2 with FOSRestBundle and JMSSerializerBundle

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

I want to handle the diferents versions of a resource with the request header 'Accept'

```
===>
GET /customer/123 HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/vnd.company.myapp.customer-v3+json

<===
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/vnd.company.myapp-v3+json

{"customer":
  {"name":"Neil Armstrong"}
}
```

I want to read the Accept header, extract the version and initialize the serializer with this version!

This is possible with FOSRestBundle?

I know I can listen kernel.request, inspect the 'Accept' header and extract the requested version from the MIME type but I don´t know how to set the serializer with this value...

I also read FOSRestBundle doc and I know that you can add new mime types in config:

```
view.mime_types: {'json': ['application/vnd.company.myapp.customer-v1+xml', 'application/vnd.company.myapp.customer-v2+xml']}
```

I need to add here all the possible mime types (with different versions)?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This won't help you for the time being, but there are opened issues regarding API Versioning.
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/pull/632

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible, see [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/versioning.html).

Your config.yml file would look something like this (use whatever regex you'd like).

```
fos_rest:
    versioning:
        enabled: true
        resolvers:
            media_type: # Accept header
                enabled: true
                regex: '/v(?P<version>[0-9\.]+)\+(json|xml)/'
        guessing_order:
            - media_type # Not needed if there's only one
    format_listener: # Must enable format_listener for versioning in Accept headers
        enabled: true
        rules: # Catch all routes to use this rule
            - { path: '*', priorities: ['json', 'xml'], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false }
    view:
        mime_types: # If there are lots of versions, can make this more dynamic. Check docs.
            json: ['application/vnd.company.myapp.customer-v1+xml', 'application/vnd.company.myapp.customer-v2+xml', 'application/vnd.company.myapp.customer-v3+json']
```